# Trigger this script as page loads

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery script, which is triggered when a checkbox is selected (or deselected). It causes the whole page to be disabled, or enabled.

It is working as intended, but I have to start the page in "edit" mode.

**I need to be able to set if the page starts in edit mode, or disabled mode when the page initially loads.**

I can easily pass a variable via PHP - but I'm not sure where/how to do it, or what to trigger?

This is my triggering script

```
<script>
    $('#switch-enable').change(function()
    {
        if ($('#switch-enable').is(':checked')) {
            $('#disabled-switches *').prop("disabled", false);  
        } else {
            $('#disabled-switches *').prop("disabled", true);   
        }
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the prop change code in a function, call it in `$(document).ready()` and set the appropriate `checked` attribute on the checkbox via `php`
eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" <?=$editModeOnStart?' checked="checked"':''?> id="switch-enable" />
<script>
  var handleSwitch = function(){
    if ($('#switch-enable').is(':checked')) {
        $('#disabled-switches *').prop("disabled", false);  
    } else {
        $('#disabled-switches *').prop("disabled", true);   
    }
  }
  $(function(){
    handleSwitch();
    $('#switch-enable').change(handleSwitch);
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editMode = '<?php echo $editMode; ?>;
});
```

and set the $editMode in php using GET

```
$editMode = $_GET['edit'];
```